# Regular Expression capturing group with optional delimiter

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

Seemed like a simple problem, I need to extract a capturing group and optionally limit the group with a delimiting string.

In the below example, I provide a delimiting string of 'cd' and expect that it would return 'ab' in all of the cases: 'ab', 'abcd', and 'abcdefg'

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expected = "ab"; // Could be more or less than two characters
    String[] tests = {"ab", "abcd", "abcdefg"};
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)cd?.*");

    for(String test : tests) {
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(test);
        if(match.matches()) {
            if(expected.equals(match.group(1)))
                System.out.println("Capture Group for test: " + test + " - " + match.group(1));
            else System.err.println("Expected " + expected + " but captured " + match.group(1));
        } else System.err.println("No match for " + test);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
    No match for ab
    Capture Group for test: abcd - ab
    Capture Group for test: abcdefg - ab
```

I thought that a lookahead might work, but I don't think that there is one that is optional (i.e. zero or more instances)

Comment: The problem is that, even if you make the first `(.*)` nongreedy, everything else in the regex - `(?:cd)` and `.*` - is optional, so the capture group will consume the entire string and there will be a match. You need to make the regex more specific. Also, rather than running a Java program for every test, you can use [this web page](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html).

Comment: I'm not really sure how I could make the regex more specific given the requirements... the length of the expected string could be one or more characters, otherwise a length limiter would work, but other than that, I don't know how else to limit it.

Comment: Is it not possible to just use `indexOf` and `substring`?

Comment: Do you see my point, though? From your regex's perspective, there's no way to distinguish between the part you want to match, the optional delimiter, and the rest of the string.

Comment: @Melv - This is part of a larger group matcher so `indexOf` and `substring` are not options

Comment: @Matt-Ball - I understand your point, which is why I thought a positive lookahead would be the solution... just can't figure out how to do it 'optionally'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?:cd.*|$)");
```

The `.*?` is non-greedy, and the rest of the regex either matches `cd` followed by anything, or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem might be that the `?` is only applying to the `d`. Try `(cd)?` instead.

Comment: Output: Fails for `abcd` and `abcdefg`